# Flag declined, but post deleted anyway?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged an answer today as being not an answer. It was declined with:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

The answer itself wasn't technically inaccurate or wrong - it was a single sentence that was completely true:

> Pointer to double is declared like `double *`.

But that's just... not an answer to the question. But then the answer was then deleted by a moderator. So it's like my flag was accepted, but not? I'm still trying to figure out the correct situations to flag answers and this is the ultimate mixed signal.

Answer (score 10):

That's my bad - I scanned the answer initially and saw exactly what you describe: a valid statement. So I declined the flag.

Then I read the comments and the question, and realized it was - in context - effectively nonsense. So I deleted it, after downvoting it.

Comment: Ok, cool. Thanks Shog. I will continue flagging away then. In cases like this, I guess I will provide a more explicit rationale in the "other" box?

Comment: I wouldn't be too concerned - I was cooking supper at the same time, so not really paying as much attention as I should've been.