# How do I handle "it's working" answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

On questions, where the code provided by the OP is supposed to work, I tend to leave a comment saying that the code is working and we need more details to reproduce the problem.

Leaving a comment rather than posting an answer ***"it's working"*** is the only proper action to take in this case, right?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43829000/962734) and I flagged it as "Not an answer", but my flag is disputed?

---

[EDIT]

Followed by the description of "Not an answer" flag:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. **It should possibly be** an edit, **a comment**, another question, or deleted altogether.

I thought it's a normal thing to flag such answers, as it actually should have been a comment (very helpfull for the OP anyway) noticing the OP that their code seems to be fine and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: The link doesn't have any answers now? Was it removed?

Comment: @Tyress yes, the answer was deleted by a mod but I also casted a delete vote on it.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Are “Your code works fine for me” answers acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable) – From the accepted answer: *"Stating that you cannot reproduce the problem described in the question is not an answer."*

Comment: Interesting question, actually... I agree with you that they should comment stating that it's working and vote/flag to close as "not reproducible" (or possibly "not enough information to debug" if it seems like the error is likely to occur *somewhere* but it doesn't occur in the code that the OP showed).

Comment: @MartinR The problem is that that accepted answer is not necessarily correct. Sometimes a comment is insufficient: the OP needs to be shown, with elaborate explanation, pix, screencast, etc., how to see that the code he has provided does work as desired in a clean project, and that therefore the source of the issue lies elsewhere. Proving that a question's premise is false (here, "this doesn't work") _is a valid answer_ and an important form of argumentation. Moreover, in the world of programming, it is a _very_ powerful pedagogical tool, teaching the OP to try things in a clean project.

Comment: @matt it may not be the correct one, but it's the sanest option.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is an answer and as such it survived the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16053734) hence the disputed flag.

**However, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43829000/7758804) was later deleted by a moderator, indicating it should have been deleted as low quality, or not an answer.** The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43828797/7758804) was also eventually deleted.

It is much better to close vote such questions as off-topic/no repro or lacking an MCVE.

As such answers are not useful use the down vote button. Do not use flags on answers that are not gibberish or seem to answer a question (not taking context into account).

The text in the flag dialog is misleading it should read:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer **a** question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

(emphasis is mine)

See the [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) for the background on that.

As remarked by Jon Clements in a comment there are extra things to take into consideration as well:

- Context - reviewers are not expected to examine every single iota of it to determine if an answer or not. It looks like it could be one - although if you do examine it in details - it's not much more than the original code.
- Sometimes, there's a language barrier (not saying there is in this case), but that first sentence could have meant "This appears to work" / "Seems like this works" and then provided corrected input code - so to all intent and purposes it looks like it could be an answer

Comment: There's two other things to take into consideration here. 1) Context - reviewers are not expected to examine every single iota of it to determine if an answer or not. It looks like it could be one - although if you do examine it in details - it's not much more than the original code. And 2) Sometimes, there's a language barrier (not saying there is in this case), but that first sentence could have meant "This appears to work" / "Seems like this works" and then provided corrected input code - so to all intent and purposes it looks like it could be an answer.

Comment: _As such answers are not useful use the down vote_ - It will take 10 DV to cancel the rep of the 2 UV, I guess they won't delete their answer until it happens

Comment: @JonClements [The context is right there at plain view for everyone to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YajCr.png) You moderators are under the impression that you are above context, [*this is simply not true*.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285491/792066) Don't apply the same to reviewers.

Comment: @AlonEitan or a couple of 20K-ers need to help a bit. Still needs to have a score <0 so although it might seem useless, down voting can still help to make it eligible for deletion.

Comment: @rene It was deleted just now :) Apparently I was wrong

Comment: @AlonEitan well, it got some mod *love* ... ninja puppies powerz ...

Comment: Ok, I got it :-) I was a little confused by the description of the flag

Comment: It is NOT an answer.  Well, no more than "I don't know" is an answer. I could go through all of Stack Overflow and post "I don't know" as an answer on every single question.  And I would expect these to get flagged as "not an answer" (and I'd expect some kind of ban for this behaviour).  Claiming that "it works" is an answer to "why doesn't this work" is nonsense.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I still have the feeling what you describe is an answer that is not useful. That warrant down votes, not flags. That a majority of this community still feel they need to be able to get rid of answers by using flags is true, but has yet to be transformed into policy.

Comment: No, this does not attempt to answer _any_ question at all ever.

Comment: _"reviewers are not expected to examine every single iota of it to determine if an answer or not"_ reviewers are also not expected to be stupid robots who don't even look at what they're doing

Answer (score 32):

Since it's not immediately obvious from the (currently) accepted answer, I'll post this separately: **If the answer consists entirely of the sentence "Your code seems to work for me," or the equivalent, then flagging it is appropriate.**  In this case, your flag was only disputed because the answer included code and vaguely resembled a real answer (which is [enough to decline a NAA flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag-the-question-%E2%86%92)).  If that code had not been there, your flag probably would have been accepted.

Comment: Of course it is an answer, it tells us that the code is right in some context, it's important to know. Though I'd prefer to have it in the comments instead probably.