# How should I handle typo answers in the Low Quality Answers queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts, low-quality-answers

Occasionally, I find one sentence answers in the Low Quality Answers queue. They are often:

> I had to restart my computer/IDE/whatever

Or *Not reproducible or caused by typos* type answers such as:

> [the return statement in the main controller was missing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34487132)

In the former example, the answer seems to be a temporary fix that does not address the underlying cause for the error. In the latter example, the question gets closed as a typo and the answer gets deleted anyway. While these are technically *'answers'*, they are very much low quality and often get deleted anyway (along with their parent question or otherwise).

As such, I am hesitant to choose <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> because, as mentioned, they are technically answers but on the other hand, I am reluctant to choose <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> because they add little/no value and tend to get deleted anyway. (Link-only answers are also technically answer attempts but are considered non-answers and get deleted).

In the cited example, I ended up going with <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd>. Did I make the right choice? How should I handle such answers in general and why?

Comment: Aside from your choice in the Low quality answers review, after you flagging these questions for closure?

Comment: @WaiHaLee Yeah, but not that this does much. I also [tag:cv-pls] them in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: I vote to delete and respond with: Do not post answers to problems caused by typo type issues, or answer with **your code works**. These issues should be called out in comments and flagged, as there is a specific close flag **Not reproducible or was caused by a typo**. Please see [How do I handle "it's working" answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348880/7758804). These questions are typically downvoted, closed and deleted, as they are of no benefit to the community.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney In that case, that should be added as a canned comment option for recommending deletion.

Comment: In the specific case of the linked answer, the question OP is also the answer OP, and a 1 rep user. I tacked on **As this is your own question, you should just delete it.**

Comment: In general, if restarting the computer/IDE/whatever helps, _that is an answer that could help someone with the same issue_, even if it's just a workaround.  That should absolutely not be deleted, _especially_ if you don't _know_ that it's just a temporary fix (although arguably even "a partial workaround is to restart your IDE; it'll be back in a few days, but it solves it temporarily" is an answer that would help someone struggling with an issue that they don't realize can be worked around in that way).

Comment: I have more mixed feelings about the typo ones.  On the one hand, the questions are of little value.  On the other hand, _deleting the answer_ makes that harder to notice, especially because not everyone can see deleted answers.  These appearing in LQA is in large part the result of some really questionable flagging from people who flag typo answers as NAA (bonus points if they don't also vote/flag to close, which happens surprisingly often...).  There's probably a separate but highly related question as to whether these flags are appropriate.

Comment: There is [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366135/7758804)

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerateresponse Isn't restarting the computer a normal step in the debugging process, and thus should have been tried before resorting to asking on SO?

Comment: My debugging process generally involves searching for the error on a search engine far before restarting.  IDE and build-system caches can take a while to rebuild, and restarting the computer or even just the IDE can be annoying and a waste of time when there's a more straightforward solution.

Comment: One more reason why questions should start in a closed state....